# Как убрать анимацию навигационного меню на bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, меню

Сделал стандартное адаптивное меню с помощью бутстрап и возникла следующая проблема. При уменьшении экрана появляется бургерное меню и когда нажимаешь на значок, что бы его открыть то текст который идет после этого меню плавно съезжает вниз а мне не нужно что бы текст съезжал вниз , как это исправить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему.

Блоку, к которому прикреплено меню, задал ширину в %. Теперь при открытии меню плавно увеличивает блок. Это довольно красиво и текст не съезжает на другие блоки.